# query wongt output to table. correct syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What am i doing wrong here?
(Know its mysql)
this else is not working it look like. user can insert same modul id many times.

```
$besvarelse = $_GET['besvarelse'];
$modulid = $_GET['modulid'];
$username = $_GET['username'];

$tilkobling = kobleTil(); 
if (!empty($besvarelse) ) {
      $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO oppgave (besvarelse, modulid, username) VALUES ('$besvarelse', '$modulid','$username')");


if($insert) {

          echo "<h1>Levering OK</h1><br>";

        }
    }
    else {

        die("<h1>Du har lever før</h1>");

    }
?>
```

Comment: Make `modulid` column unique on your table then

Comment: get no error. just making new row i table . need to check some how if user has delivery this mudul before. any idea how i can do that?

Comment: but evert user should have option do deliver 6 modulid (contain value from 1-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try with this and post the errors that PHP shows, please:**

```
//Assuming that connection to mysql server its done somewhere with mysql_connect()

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
explode($_GET);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET); //Just to see what's on the variables...
echo "</pre>;

// $tilkobling = kobleTil(); Need to explain this line

if (!empty($besvarelse) ) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO oppgave (besvarelse, modulid, username) VALUES ('$besvarelse', '$modulid','$username')";

if($insert = mysql_query($sql))
       {
          echo "<h1>Levering OK</h1><br>";

        }

    else {

        die("<h1>Du har lever før</h1>");

    }
} // you were missmatching the IF closing bracket

?>
```

Comment: i have no error. think i have to change something. can i somehov check if the $_GET value $modulid = $_GET['modulid'];
$username = $_GET['username']; exist on same row, output messsage that is allready delivered?

Comment: Yes. I edited the code above to show the _GET variables before send it to mysql.

Comment: Got it to wor by putting this in the $check:      $check = mysql_query("select * from oppgave where username ='{$_SESSION['user_name']}' and modulid='$modulid'");

Answer (score 0):

try to check for exist rows like

```
$besvarelse = $_GET['besvarelse'];
$modulid = $_GET['modulid'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
$tilkobling = kobleTil(); 
    if (!empty($besvarelse) ) {
     // check exist moduleid
      $check = mysql_query("select * from oppgave where modulid = '$modulid'");
      $conut_rows= mysql_num_rows($check);
      if($conut_rows > 0) {
        echo "module id already exist";
      }
      else {
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO oppgave (besvarelse, modulid, username) VALUES ('$besvarelse', '$modulid','$username')");
        if($insert) {
           echo "<h1>Levering OK</h1><br>";
        }
        else {
           die("<h1>Du har lever før</h1>");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: this works fine but another user is trying to deliver same modul as another user is getting message back that it delivered

Comment: you need to refine code according to your requirement